# How to implement a iterator or generator for my Delegate class?

Tags: python-3.x, delegates, iterator, generator

I implemented a `Delegate` class in Python 3, which wraps a function object in a object instance. It's possible to register multiple function objects on one delegate (in .NET terminology it's a `MultiCastDelegate`). Assumed all registered functions accept the same parameters, it's possible to invoke the delegate and call all functions at once.

`Delegate` implementation:

```
class Delegate:
  def __init__(self, *funcs):
    self.__invocationList__ = []
    for func in funcs:
      self.__invocationList__.append(func)

  def __iadd__(self, func):
    self.__invocationList__.append(func)
    return self

  def __isub__(self, func):
    self.__invocationList__.remove(func)
    return self

  def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if (len(self.__invocationList__) == 1):
      return self.__invocationList__[0](*args, **kwargs)
    else:
      res = {}
      for func in self.__invocationList__:
        res[func] = func(*args, **kwargs)
      return res

  @property
  def isMulticast(self):
    return (len(self.__invocationList__) > 1)
```

Usage examples:

```
def test1():
  return 5
def test2(a, b):
  return a + b
def test3(a, b):
  return a * b + 15

delegate = Delegate(test1)
result = delegate()
print("test1: {0}".format(result))

delegate = Delegate(test2)
result = delegate(3, 8)
print("test2: {0}".format(result))

delegate += test3
results = delegate(2, 9)
print("test2: {0}".format(results[test2]))
print("test3: {0}".format(results[test3]))
```

I would like to implement an iterator or generator on this class, so it's possible to use the delegate in `for` loops.

**How could it look like?**

```
# loop over every result from delegate, call with parameters 4 and 18
for result in delegate(4, 18):
  print("function={0}  result={1}".format(*result))
```

The iterators `__next__()` method should return a tuple consisting of the function-object and return value.

**What I tried so far:**

```
class Delegate:
  # ...
  # see code from above

  def __iter__(self):
    print("Delegate.__iter__():")

    class iter:
      def __init__(self2, *args, **kwargs):
        print(str(args))
        self2.__args =    args
        self2.__kwargs =  kwargs
        self2.__index = 0

      def __iter__(self2):
        return self2

      def __next__(self2):
        if (self2.__index == len(self.__invocationList__)):
          raise StopIteration
        func = self.__invocationList__[self2.__index]
        self2.__index += 1
        return func(*self2.__args, **self2.__kwargs)

    return iter()
```

Because the constructor method is already in use by the `Delegate` creation itself, I implemented the iterator as a nested class. But unfortunately, I can not pass the call parameters *args and **kwargs to the iterator.

So my questions:

- Is it possible and wise the implement a iterator / generator pattern for delegates?
- What should I change to get it working?

I just tried to implement the iterator pattern. If it works, I would like to upgrade it to a generator - if possible :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this, but I gave it a shot. It is not well tested, but it will help you on the way to solve your task. Here is the code:

```
class Delegate:
  class IterDelegate:
    def __init__(this, invocationList, *args, **kwargs):
      this.__args = args
      this.__kwargs = kwargs
      this._invocationList = invocationList

    def __iter__(this):
      this.__index = 0
      return this

    def __next__(this):
      if this.__index < len(this._invocationList):
        func = this._invocationList[this.__index]
        this.__index += 1
        return (func.__name__, func(*this.__args, **this.__kwargs))
      raise StopIteration

  def __init__(self, func):
    if (type(func) == 'list'):
      self._invocationList = func
    else:
      self._invocationList = [func]

  def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.IterDelegate(self._invocationList, *args, **kwargs)

  def __iadd__(self, func):
    self._invocationList.append(func)
    return self

  def __isub__(self, func):
    self._invocationList.remove(func)
    return self


def test2(a, b):
  return a + b

def test1(*args):
  return 6

delegate = Delegate(test2)

delegate += test1

results = delegate(2,3)

for r in results:
  print("function={0}  result={1}".format(*r))
```

This will give the results

```
function=test2  result=5
function=test1  result=6
```